# Calling a non-interrupt function after an interrupt in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I want to run a piece of code after receiving a hardware interrupt on a Linux machine, however, I have discovered that I can't run the function I want to perform in an interrupt context. If I have the function I want called from an IRQ, it causes a problem for the kernel, because the code is lengthy and involves sleeping with the processor.

So what I want to do is for my kernel module to receive an interrupt and acknowledge it, and then the next chance it gets for it to run a piece of code, but not do so in an IRQ handler.

I found the "poll" method of calling functions on demand, which I thought might be useful, but the examples I saw were all versions of getting the kernel module to interact with external userspace code. What I'm hoping is that  in my interrupt handler I can toggle some flag bit to signal that it is time to perform my desired function, and then for my kernel module to call my desired function whenever it sees that flag is set, but without doing it as an interrupt itself.

Is this sort of thing possible? Or if not, how else can I link a function to a hardware interrupt without using an IRQ handler?

Comment: You have already [asked the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158406/how-to-trigger-a-function-in-kernel-module-interrupt) on the same(or similar) topic. [The comment on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158406/how-to-trigger-a-function-in-kernel-module-interrupt#comment85321770_49158406) suggested an article about tasklets ans workqueues. Have you read this article?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have read that article, according to it a "tasklet" is atomic and therefore cannot be used for my purpose, because as I say I need to sleep with my processor. Therefore I thought I should be more specific and ask how to flag a module to perform a function at some time in the future, not perform an action or spin off a thread from the ISR

Comment: Hm, the article notes workqueues, but doesn't describe it. But actually workqueue is what you need. Just google any example about it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I had figured a workqueue was another name for a tasklet. I will look for that then.

Comment: No, workqueue and tasklet are *different* things. You correctly noted that tasklet cannot sleep, but workqueue can.